# Blank line in python function docstring breaks Doxygen special commands

Tags: python, doxygen

Adding a blank line in the docstring of a function within a class breaks the parsing of the Doxygen Special Command.

This works

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        """! This is a public member
        @param val (int): integer input
        """
        self.bar = val
```

but this does not

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        """! This is a public member

        @param val (int): integer input
        """
        self.bar = val
```

Blank lines are fine in docstrings when they are not within class functions, so there's a lack of consistency. And I like the blank line for aesthetic reasons and to break the inputs from the description.

How do I make it work with the blank line?

Comment: OK, nice to know, but what's your question?

Comment: I've edited the post to provide a clear question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of doxygen is not specified, so I tested with the current version (doxygen 1.9.5) and a default doxygen settings file. Also what exactly is missing is not specified.

The good version will result in:

[image]

and the "broken" version will result in (added a 1 to the class so I only need one file):

[image]

The problem here is the indentation. Due to the empty line the indentation is reset and the Markdown processing will see the `@param` line with an indentation >=4 and thus as a code section.

There are a couple of solutions:

- set `MARKDOWN_SUPPORT=NO` , not really a solution as this will take away a lot of other nice features.
- adjust the code:

  ```
        """!
        This is a public member

        @param val (int): integer input
        """
  ```
- adjust the code:

  ```
        """! This is a public member

  @param val (int): integer input
        """
  ```